# Differentiate button and row click event in Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

In my Application in UITableView i put UIButton in every cell.

but when i click on Button then **some times button event will come and some time Cell's Row clicked**.

I need to get **button click event** all the time **when button click** and **row click event** when **row clicked**.

How to come over this issue ?

All the Row are identical (means i didn't use reusable).

My code for this is...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell1"];

    [cell clearsContextBeforeDrawing];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(5,220,70, 30);
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"button == %ld",(long)indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(methodOfButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
}

return cell;

}
```

Any tutorial, code, link will be great help.

Comment: If you Want to Navigate through your UIButton placed on every cell then you don`t need UITableView Delegate DidSelectRawAtIndexpath:. You can navigate through view`s via that UIButton`s IBAction.

Comment: button click event will lead me to different page and row click event will lead me to another page. so need both the event. not only any one click event.

Comment: Then keep both.. Give button selector and also implement DidSelectRawAtIndexPath:

Comment: but it's not working. i did it already as i told in my answer. but the button's click event will come some time and some time the row will clicked.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're tapping the correct area? It's possible that you're off the button's tappable area by just a point or 2 and it's triggering the row tap instead.

Comment: agree with [stonz2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2788608/stonz2)

Comment: no. tap area is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem you're seeing happen when user tapped close to the button but not on it. In other interface elements you will not notice this, since no other event will be generated but in your cases 'didSelectRow' will fire.

You need to make sure button occupies as much room as possible on the cell (at least full cell height). This way you will get user less chance to miss tap. Right now your button is only 30px tall, what the height of the cell?

Comment: button is fixed in cell. and the area is not a problem.